# adding detail information to django listview object in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a listview in which I'm hoping to insert additional details about the object (activity duration and average power) in the same row as the link to the object detail (the best way to describe it would be that I want some detailview attributes inserted into the listview). At the moment, the best I can achieve is a separate context dictionary listed below the object_list, as shown in this screen shot:

[image]

And the following is my listview:

```
class RideDataListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = RideData 
    context_object_name='object_list'
    template_name='PMC/ridedata_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(RideDataListView, self).get_queryset()

        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        model = RideData
        context = super(RideDataListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        records = list(RideData.objects.all().values())
        actdict2={}
        id=[]
        ap=[]
        actdur=[]
        for record in records:
            actdf=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(record)
            id.append(actdf['id'].iloc[0])
            ap.append(actdf['watts'].mean())
            actdur.append(str(timedelta(seconds=len(actdf['time']))))
            actdf2=pd.DataFrame()
            actdf2['id']=id
            actdf2['ap']=ap
            actdf2['actdur']=actdur
        actdict2=actdf2.to_dict('records')    
        context['actdict']=actdict2

        context['actdur']=actdur

        return context
```

What I haven't been able to nail down in my research is if there is a way to either a) annotate the queryset with stuff from context or b) loop through the context dictionary 'actdict' within the object_list loop (doesn't seem possible based on some attempts) or c) include individual lists (ap and actdur as additions to to query. Just curious for some additional leads to add some more object detail to the basic listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual solution to this was to add to queryset object within def get_queryset

```
def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(RideDataListView, self).get_queryset()
        for obj in queryset:
            record=list(obj.watts)
            actdf=pd.DataFrame()
            actdf['watts']=record
            obj.actdur=str(timedelta(seconds=len(actdf['watts'])))
            obj.ap=actdf['watts'].mean()

        return queryset
```

This returned the additional summary information I wanted to include in the listview that is also used in detailview
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `context` is intended to contain your data, but the way it is displayed rely on the **HTML template** you will use : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/